# Fetch Unique Column Values from a JArray

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I am trying to get only Unique IDs from a JSON response. I tried to parse and select only token Ids but it is failing. **What is the best and fastest way to get only the Ids?**

**Code:**

```
JArray jArray = new JArray();
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(jArray.ToString(Formatting.Indented)); 
var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Here is my sample JSON Array:**

```
[
  {
    "Timestamp": "2020-11-24T08:25:46.6531855Z",
    "ID": "8c316aca-b930-421f-851c-17d618b61fa1",
    "Message": "New User Registered"
  },
  {
    "Timestamp": "2020-11-24T08:25:46.6531855Z",
    "ID": "8c316aca-b930-421f-851c-17d618b61fa1",
    "Message": "User details updated"
  },
  {
    "Timestamp": "2020-11-24T08:25:46.6531855Z",
    "ID": "a23shaga-2wd3-fky6-851c-43524fbfgsa",
    "Message": "New User Registered"
  }
]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
8c316aca-b930-421f-851c-17d618b61fa1
a23shaga-2wd3-fky6-851c-43524fbfgsa
```

Comment: The fastest way is to use a streaming JsonReader. Json.NET is pretty slow. Use a different library for working with json. I suppose, the response comes in UTF-8 encoding - take the library that works directly with this encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create the object with the properties timestamp, id and message- then deserialize the json to this object.

But for now you can try below and should work out well for you.

```
JArray jArray = new JArray();          
jArray = JArray.Parse(@"[
{
    ""Timestamp"": ""2020-11-24T08:25:46.6531855Z"",
    ""ID"": ""8c316aca-b930-421f-851c-17d618b61fa1"",
    ""Message"": ""New User Registered""
},
{
    ""Timestamp"": ""2020-11-24T08:25:46.6531855Z"",
    ""ID"": ""8c316aca-b930-421f-851c-17d618b61fa1"",
    ""Message"": ""User details updated""
},
{
    ""Timestamp"": ""2020-11-24T08:25:46.6531855Z"",
    ""ID"":""a23shaga-2wd3-fky6-851c-43524fbfgsa"",
    ""Message"": ""New User Registered""
}]");


var newList = jArray.Where(y=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y["ID"].ToString()))
            .GroupBy(x => x["ID"])
            .Select(x => x.First()).ToList();


foreach (var item in newList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["ID"]);
}
```

Here newList contains only unique data w.r.t 'ID'
Just replace the entire string in my example with the async resp you are getting.

NOTE : You should either make the source return unique or create a new object and deserialize it instead of using JObject, this will help you when you have bigger lists

So below is the outcome i think you are looking for

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Manti_Core, If ID have any null values, i would like to filtering with null values.This is not working. Like
jArray.Where(x => x["Id"] != null).GroupBy(x=>x["Id"]).Select(x => x.First()).ToList()

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS you are almost correct, but you need it to be string to even compare it. Try updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the distinct `ID` values from your `JArray`, filtering out possible nulls:

```
jArray = JArray.Parse(resp);
var ids = jArray.Children<JObject>()
                .Select(jo => (string)jo["ID"])   // NOTE: this is case sensitive
                .Where(s => s != null)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
```

Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gaQ1n0